# Reading notifications using AccessibilityService

Tags: android, xml, notifications, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I've recently tried to read incoming notifications using `AccessibilityService`.
I know reading notifications using `NotificationListenerService`, but that's not what I need (for compatibility with lower android versions).
My problem is, `OnServiceConnected()` never get called, even though in my settings, I've gave my app the neccessary premisions.
Here is my code:

```
public class NotificationAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService{

    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        Log.d("Tortuga", "AccessibilityService Connected");
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK;
        info.notificationTimeout = 100;
        setServiceInfo(info);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e) {
        Log.d("Tortuga","FML");
        if (e.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {
            Log.d("Tortuga","Recieved event");
            Parcelable data = e.getParcelableData();
            if (data instanceof Notification) {
                Log.d("Tortuga","Recieved notification");
                Notification notification = (Notification) data;
                Log.d("Tortuga","ticker: " + notification.tickerText);
                Log.d("Tortuga","icon: " + notification.icon);
                Log.d("Tortuga", "notification: "+ e.getText());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

And my XML:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service
            android:name="com.tortuga.shutapp.NotificationAccessibilityService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
        </service>
```

**xml\accessibilityservice.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeNotificationStateChanged"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100" />
```

Please help, I'm lost. I'm currently running on Nexus 5.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't have any comment to add to your question, but I just want to ask what are you doing in NotificationService class??

Can you please provide me the link or this service class.

Comment: @Javi Dofrsman i m not getting my service name in Setting - Accessibility - your service"    how can i start service  ?

Comment: @Javi Dorfsman have you try this code on android api 4.4.4,I am testing it on kitkat and not working.Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you start the service？ In "Setting - Accessibility - your service"

Comment: So simple! That was part of the solution! I also did a mistake in the name of the service.. Thanks!

Comment: how do you restore the notifications in local?

Comment: **IMPORTANT !** once you reinstall the application you need to re-enable your service in the Accessibility Settings.