# How to activate AccessibilityService on my android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service, android-notifications, accessibilityservice

I created an Accessibility Service for obtain notifications, but this service is not run, I read some any questions in this forum and read a possible solution, [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286681/reading-notifications-using-accessibilityservice) one user posts a possible solution what is activate service on android following this route Settings > Accessibility > "MyService" but in my android not shows my service and I not have any idea for cause this, my service and configurations [is in this publication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108388/accessibility-service-is-not-run).

Any help, really would be very helpful. Thanks...

Comment: how u resolve your issue i m also not getting in Settings > Accessibility > "MyService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in my android not shows my service and I not have any idea for cause this

Either your app is not installed on the device, [the app's manifest is not set up properly](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html#manifest) to advertise an accessibility service, or the device has a bug.

Comment: Thanks for you aportation, my app is deployed on the device, in the tutorial I see the configuration for manifest and I've tried but not function, my configurations in manifest is similar and still not run, my class which implement this service is not call and I do not know why...