# Listen to notifications using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, notification-listener

I'm a beginner to android app development. I waned to access incoming notifications from my flutter app. I tried https://pub.dev/packages/notifications package. But I can't find how it works.

I also tried to use the NotificationListener but can't figure it out.

Please help if you can.

Comment: Hi!, the documentation is pretty straightforward, what exactly did you try and why you think that is not working? Are you using Firebase to sent the notification? Maybe you can try with https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

Comment: I'm not sure you're getting me. I want to access notifications of others apps through my flutter app.

Comment: You may need to implement a https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService in. the native part and use a StreamChannel to sent the data to Flutter. Also there are some cases where it may not work as you expect. Other solution is to read notifications using AccessibilityService https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286681/reading-notifications-using-accessibilityservice

Answer (score 0):

The [notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/notifications) package listens to notifications/push messages received by the device. The messages received should be handled inside `onData`.

```dart
Notifications _notifications;
StreamSubscription<NotificationEvent> _subscription;

...

void onData(NotificationEvent event) {
  debugPrint('Event received: $event');
}

void startListening() {
  _notifications = new Notifications();
  try {
    _subscription = _notifications!.notificationStream!.listen(onData);
  } on NotificationException catch (exception) {
    debugPrint(exception);
  }
}
```